# Problema con Layouts en Java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, layout

Estoy haciendo un programa en el cual hay un JFrame un tanto rebuscado.

Cabe resaltar que no soy un experto desarrollando GUIs o manejando muchos Layouts en Java, pero creo que me las he podido arreglar bastante.

A continuación muestro la distribución de componentes en el JFrame con un código de colores para distinguir cada uno:

[image: Distribución de componentes en el JFrame]

No quise caer en la tentación de setear en null el Layout del JPanel y acomodar las cosas a mi gusto, porque, por experiencia, conozco las contras de hacerlo.

Investigué sobre varios Layouts posibles y encontré el fabuloso [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). Descargué y leí su documentación e incluso busqué tutoriales de cómo hacer uso del mismo y me sorprendió la facilidad con la que se puede trabajar.

Empecé por la mitad izquierda del JFrame, donde tengo los JLabel, JSeparator, JCheckbox y un JButton. Para empezar, seteé el MigLayout de la forma:

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 2"));
```

Lo hice de esta manera porque necesito que los JCheckBox se muestren en columnas de a 2.

Los JCheckbox que se muestran están almacenados en distintos `ArrayList<JCheckBox>`.

Para implementar esto, hice un método simple como el siguiente:

```
/**
 * Este método se encarga de colocar en el panel los checkboxes
 * junto con una etiqueta que los distinga.
 * 
 * @param panel Panel donde se colocarán los checkboxes.
 * @param cbSet Conjunto de checkboxes a colocar.
 * @param title Texto de la etiqueta de acompañamiento.
 */
 private void addCheckboxes(JPanel panel, ArrayList<JCheckBox> cbSet, String title) {
     panel.add(new JLabel(title), "wrap");

     for (JCheckBox cb : cbSet)
         panel.add(cb);
        
     panel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL), "growx, span");
 }
```

En palabras, este método recibe el arreglo de JCheckbox, coloca en el JPanel un JLabel con un título personalizado, coloca en el JPanel la cantidad de JCheckbox que haya en el arreglo recibido, y al finalizar coloca un JSeparator para una mejor legibilidad.

Luego de este método, simplemente agrego el botón inferior de la forma:

```
JButton okButton = new JButton("Aceptar");

//Aquí agregué el ActionListener para el botón que no viene al caso...

panel.add(okButton, "growx, span");
```

Luego de todo esto, tengo un resultado bastante satisfactorio, como se puede ver:

[image: Distribución izquierda de los componentes en el JFrame]

Lo único que me llama la atención es el espacio en blanco que queda en la parte derecha del JFrame.

Buscando ahora agregar el JTextArea de la parte derecha del JFrame para luego agregar los JButtons debajo de dicho JTextArea, traté de hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
textArea.setVisible(true);

panel.add(textArea, "east");
```

De acuerdo a la [documentación de MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html), los comandos `east` o `dock east` hacen que el componente quede a la derecha. Probé implementarlo y no estoy teniendo buenos resultados.

Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:

[image: Error en parte derecha del JFrame]

Por algún motivo, el JTextArea está totalmente angosto y aunque utilice el método `setSize()` su ancho no varía para nada. La altura del JTextArea sí la puedo modificar, pero el ancho es completamente inútil.

Probé agregarle más parámetros que encontré en la documentación a la hora de agregar el JTextArea, por ejemplo `growx`, e incluso probé con `span` y `wrap` para ver si cambiaba *algo*. Desgraciadamente no.

Probé, además, cambiar el tamaño del JFrame pero no aportó nada.

Otra cosa que me llama la atención, es que cuando agrego el JTextArea todos los JCheckBox, JLabel, JSeparator y JButton agregados se corren hacia la izquierda y quedan pegados al borde del JFrame, lo cual no es muy agradable a la vista.

Sospecho que todo esto tiene que ver con haber inicializado el Layout con la condición de que no hayan más de 2 columnas, pero no estoy seguro, ya que si seteo el Layout de la forma:

```
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

y el `wrap` de los JCheckBox lo hago dentro del método que los agrega, el resultado es el mismo: el JTextArea angosto y todo apretado a la izquierda del JFrame.

He leído que se pueden combinar varios JPanel con distintos Layouts para lograr lo que busco pero no sé qué tan sencillo será por la cantidad de cosas que tiene el JFrame.

Quisiera seguir utilizando MigLayout por su simpleza; cualquier ayuda o consejo sobre el uso de este Layout me sirve muchísimo, y cualquier recomendación con otros métodos es completamente bienvenida.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se solucionó con tener un JPanel "maestro", un JPanel "izquierdo" y un JPanel "derecho".

En el JPanel izquierdo agregué los componentes sin problemas, en el JPanel derecho agregué el JTextArea y los JTextButton y luego agregué ambos paneles al panel "maestro", cuyo Layout es un BorderLayout y luego simplemente fue cuestión de hacer:

```
masterPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
masterPanel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

this.add(masterPanel);
```